# How to break out of while loop after taking in all the inputs?

Tags: java, while-loop, infinite

I have a while loop which detects if sc.hasNext() is true and takes in the list of inputs typed, adding it to the list textEditor one by one.

```
         while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            if (!(line.isEmpty())){
                textEditor.addString(line);
            }
        }
        sc.close();
        textEditor.printAll();
    }
}
```

However, when I type in a list of strings e.g.

```
oneword
two words
Hello World
hello World
```

the loop does not stop and the method printAll() is not called. How do I break out of the while loop?

Comment: What type of object is sc?

Comment: "break;" and don't close stdin.

Comment: For yourself and for the other contributors, please indent the code.

Comment: sc is the scanner created by Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); @BretC

Comment: Assuming `sc` is an instance of `Scanner` `hasNext()` will wait for the next input. It doesn't know when you are done so you need to find some way to tell it, e.g. by pressing enter again (you'd get an empty line) or yet better sending input like `end` and if you get that you break the loop. Quote from the [JavaDoc on `hasNext()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()): "This method may block while waiting for input to scan."

Comment: Hmmms, doesn't the if condition that (!(line.isEmpty())) not let the scanner know that once it hits the empty line it'll break out of the loop already?

Comment: when do you want to break out? (e.g.  empty line, after the first input, after a specific input...)

Comment: `if(!(line.isEmpty())` doesn't let the _scanner_ know anything. It just doesn't add empty lines to `textEditor`. If you want to break the loop _you_ have to do so, e.g. via `if(line.isEmpty()) { break; } else { /*add here*/ }`.

Comment: I want to break out of an empty line! @kai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `break` in the `while` statement so you go in infinite loop.

I adapted your example with a simple `System.out.println`. Take a look at the new `while` condition, it will exit the while statement when an empty String is received :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String line;
while (!(line = sc.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Received line : " + line);
    //textEditor.addString(line);
}
sc.close();

System.out.println("The end");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can break out of the loop by using the break statement:

```
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        if (!(line.isEmpty())){
            textEditor.addString(line);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    textEditor.printAll();
```

(Btw don't close stdout, stderr or stdin,  that is in Java: System.out, System.err and System.in)

Comment: Hi, I've tried it this way as well, but my loop is still stuck in an infinite loop and printAll() is not called!

Comment: Now that puzzled me for a moment too, but its trivial: use sc.hasNextLine() instead of sc.hasNext() ;)